# How to Fixed TopMenu? ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net

No Fixed

[image]

Fixed

[image]

fixed html (_Layout Side)

```
<div style="text-align:center; max-width:1200px; min-width:1200px; min-height:30px; padding:5px 0; text-align:left; left:26.3%; position:fixed; z-index:1" class="container">
    <a style="color:#e2c75b; font-weight:bold; font-size:20px; text-decoration:none;" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">
        <img src="~/Images/abc.png" height="30" width="30" style="border: 0; float: left; margin-right: 10px;"/>
        <span>ABC</span>
    </a>
</div>

<main role="main" class="pb-3">
    @RenderBody()
</main>
```

This will overlap.

Readability is bad. I'm sorry.Please.

I want hope it comes out like a picture No Fixed. when fixed

Comment: Please explain the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I see you are creating a fixed div to the top and it is overlapping rest of your html elements. It is a simple thing to understand, when you fix something to top you should give enough space to the other elements. And I notice you are using `bootstrap4` because there is a class `pb-3` that you are using, then I would suggest besides reinventing the wheel, you should use bootstrap classes to achieve what you are doing.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="~/Images/abc.png" height="30" width="30" style="border: 0; float: left; "/>
  </a>

  <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <!-- Navbar links -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Now you should set the padding of body or margin of the div element that contains rest of your body.

```
<main role="main" class="pb-3" style='margin-top: 80px'>
    @RenderBody()
</main>
```

If you still want to stick to your own code instead of bootstrap then just set the relevant margin of the main element that you have.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't speak English.I solved the problem with your answer. Thank you very much. I used some of your answers to make the answers I wanted.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I used Jamshaid Kamran answer like this.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-white navbar-dark fixed-top" style="background-color:white;width:100%; height:40px;">
    <div style="text-align:left; width:1200px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">
        <a style="color:#e2c75b; font-weight:bold; font-size:18px; text-decoration:none;" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">
            <img src="~/Images/abc.png" height="24" width="24" style="border: 0; margin-right: 0px;" />
            <span>NcoreSoft</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</nav>
```